We need to calculate $\ker \alpha$
The symbol algebra $\Sigma _{per}$ defines how the subalgebra
$$\Sigma _{per}\subset C_{per}\left ( S^*M \right )\oplus \Phi _p\left ( \mathbb{S}^1 \right )\oplus \Phi _p\left ( \mathbb{S}^1 \right )$$
consisting of triples $a=(a_{int},a_c^{+},a_c^{-})$, subject to the matching condition
$\sigma _{int}$ is an integral operator or its analogue, then its core may include functions or elements that integrate into zero

$M = S^1 \times \mathbb{R}$ - infinite cylinder
$T^2 = S^1 \times S^1$ - torus
$S^*M = M \times S^1$ - cospherical bundle
$C(S^*M)$ - space of smooth functions on $S^*M$
$C_{\text{per}}(S^*M)$ - algebra of inner symbols, periodic at infinity:

$$C_{\text{per}}(S^*M) = \{a \in C(S^*M) \mid a(x, t + 2\pi k, \xi, p) = a(x, t, \xi, p) \; \forall t \ge 2\pi, k \ge 0 \; \text{and} \; \forall t \le -2\pi, k \le 0\}$$
There is a mapping
$$C_{\text{per}}(S^*M) \xrightarrow{\alpha} C(S^*T^2) \oplus C(S^*T^2)$$
$$a \mapsto (a_+ = a|_{t \ge 2\pi}, \; a_- = a|_{t \le -2\pi})$$
which associates with the inner symbol $a$ its periodic components at infinity

We need to calculate $\ker \alpha$

My attempt:
Consider the mapping
$$ \alpha : C_{\text{per}}(S^*M) \to C(S^*T^2) \oplus C(S^*T^2)$$
defined as
$$ a \mapsto (a_+ = a|_{t \geq 2\pi}, a_- = a|_{t \leq -2\pi})$$
This mapping associates an internal symbol $a$ with its periodic components on $\pm \infty$. Now we need to determine which functions $a$ belong to the kernel of this mapping, that is, for which $\alpha(a) = 0$. This means that both $a_+ = 0$ and $a_-$ are zero
$$
\ker \alpha = \left \{  a \in C_{\text{per}}(S^*M) \mid \alpha(a) = (0, 0) \right \}
$$
For a function $a$ this means that $a$ must be zero at both ends, $t \geq 2\pi$ and $t \leq -2\pi$. That is, $a(x, t, \xi, p) = 0$ for all $t \geq 2\pi$ and $t \leq -2\pi$. Since $a$ is periodic on $S^*M$ with period $2\pi$, this means that $a$ must be zero everywhere on $S^*M$. This is because if $a$ is zero at the ends and continues periodically, then $a$ must be zero throughout $S^*M$. Means
$$\ker \alpha = \left \{ a \in C_{\text{per}}(S^*M) \mid a \text{ equal to zero by } S^*M \right \} = \left \{ 0 \right \}$$
I realized that the solution is incorrect, but I cannot calculate $\ker \alpha $ otherwise, since for me $a \in \ker \alpha\Rightarrow a|_{t \geq 2\pi} = 0 \quad \text{and} \quad a|_{t \leq -2\pi} = 0$. The answer must be non-zero. Can someone help with this?
